# How can I test the method which has several methods inside it in Springboot?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, spy

```
public CartPriceResponse cartSelectAll(final String check, final User user) {
    List<Cart> carts = cartRepository.findByUser(user);
    List<CartPricePerSellerResponse> cartPricePerSellerResponses = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Cart cart : carts) {
        cart.setIsSelected(check.equals("true"));
        cartPricePerSellerResponses.add(cartPricePerSeller(user, cart.getItem().getSeller()));
    }
    final CartPriceTotalResponse cartPriceTotalResponse = cartPriceTotal(user);

    return CartPriceResponse.builder()
            .cartPricePerSellerResponses(cartPricePerSellerResponses)
            .cartPriceTotalResponse(cartPriceTotalResponse)
            .build();
}
```

Here is the one I want it to test, it takes the boolean as argument and if it is true it sets all items isSelected to be 'true'.
And cartPricePerSeller will be calculating everything about per seller and cartPriceTotal will do the same thing for all items in the cart.

The thing is I have tested cartPricePerSeller and cartPriceTotal already so no need to test them but I don't know how to mock or spy them.

And inside of cartPricePerSeller is calling another public method for calculating the shippingFee per each seller.

I think something is going off and it needs some refactoring but I really have no idea how to do that.

I will be really appreciated if you give me any little hints to make it clear.

```
public CartPricePerSellerResponse cartPricePerSeller(User user, Seller seller) {
    final List<Cart> carts = cartRepository.findByUserAndIsSelectedTrue(user);

    final List<Cart> cartList = carts.stream().filter(cart -> cart.getItem().getSeller().equals(seller)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    long cartTotalPricePerSeller = 0;
    int cartTotalQuantityPerSeller = 0;

    for (Cart cart : cartList) {
        cartTotalPricePerSeller += cart.getItemOption().getItemPrice().getPriceNow() * cart.getQuantity();
        cartTotalQuantityPerSeller += cart.getQuantity();
    }
    return CartPricePerSellerResponse.builder()
            .sellerId(seller.getId())
            .itemTotalPricePerSeller(cartTotalPricePerSeller)
            .itemTotalQuantityPerSeller(cartTotalQuantityPerSeller)
            .itemShippingFeePerSeller(shippingFeeCheck(seller.getId(), cartTotalPricePerSeller))
            .build();
}

public CartPriceTotalResponse cartPriceTotal(User user) {
    final List<Cart> carts = cartRepository.findByUserAndIsSelectedTrue(user);

    long cartTotalPrice = 0;
    int cartTotalQuantity = 0;
    int cartTotalShippingFee = 0;

    final List<Seller> sellers = carts.stream().map(Cart::getItem).map(Item::getSeller).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Seller seller : sellers) {
        final CartPricePerSellerResponse cartPricePerSellerResponse = this.cartPricePerSeller(user, seller);

        cartTotalPrice += cartPricePerSellerResponse.getItemTotalPricePerSeller();
        cartTotalQuantity += cartPricePerSellerResponse.getItemTotalQuantityPerSeller();
        cartTotalShippingFee += cartPricePerSellerResponse.getItemShippingFeePerSeller();
    }
    return CartPriceTotalResponse.builder()
            .cartTotalPrice(cartTotalPrice)
            .cartTotalQuantity(cartTotalQuantity)
            .cartTotalShippingFee(cartTotalShippingFee)
            .build();
}
```

And I am sorry if I break any rules here. This is my very first post

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Why do you need to mock anything? Methods usually call other methods, but that doesn't mean you need a mock. What is the difficulty in writing a test for this method?

Comment: ndc85430 thanks for your reply. What I want to ask is do I need to mock them again for the method is working? If I didn't mock the inside methods it is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What specifically isn't working and how isn't it working?

Comment: Because I tried to mock the one under the test. It was my misunderstanding at all. You gave me a big hint. Thx

Answer (score 1):

- Public methods can be mocked and tested separately
- Private methods should be tested through the public ones
- For the public method you are testing (let's say `m1()`, if it's calling to another public method - let's say `m2()`. Then you can absolutely mock `m2()` by using [**Spy**](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy), then `m2()` can be tested separately.